# Tikz cuts the edge of arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to generate a simple diagram of the BEC channel, but the edges of the arrows
that point to the same point looks weird.
Can anybody explain what is the right way to draw that diagram?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\tikzset{addition/.style={draw,circle,append after command={
            [shorten >=\pgflinewidth, shorten <=\pgflinewidth,]
            (\tikzlastnode.north) edge (\tikzlastnode.south)
            (\tikzlastnode.east) edge (\tikzlastnode.west)
        }
    }
}
\tikzset{line/.style={draw, -latex',shorten <=1bp,shorten >=1bp}}

\tikzstyle{block}=[draw, rectangle, minimum size=2em]
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\node[anchor=south west] at (-0.4,-0.2) {$1$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (-0.4,2-0.2) {$0$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (3+0.1,-0.2) {$1$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (3+0.1,2-0.2) {$0$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (3,1-0.25) {$?$};
\draw[->] (0,0) --node [below,midway,font=\small] {$1-\epsilon$} (3,0) ;
\draw[->] (0,2) --node [above,midway,font=\small] {$1-\epsilon$} (3,2) ;
\draw[->] (0,0) --node [above,midway,font=\small] {$\epsilon$} (3,1) ;
\draw[->] (0,2) --node [below,midway,font=\small] {$\epsilon$} (3,1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is the result I get]

while what I want it to look like:
[image: What I want]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arrows.meta` library introduced with Tikz 3.0 allows you to use the Triangle arrows.
Here, with `20:5pt 3` parameter which determine angle and length.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>={Triangle[angle=20:5pt 3]}]
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,fit,calc,positioning,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{addition/.style={draw,circle,append after command={
            [shorten >=\pgflinewidth, shorten <=\pgflinewidth,]
            (\tikzlastnode.north) edge (\tikzlastnode.south)
            (\tikzlastnode.east) edge (\tikzlastnode.west)
        }
    }
}
%\tikzset{line/.style={draw, -latex',shorten <=1bp,shorten >=1bp}}

\tikzstyle{block}=[draw, rectangle, minimum size=2em]
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>={Triangle[angle=20:5pt 3]}]
\node[anchor=south west] at (-0.4,-0.2) {$1$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (-0.4,2-0.2) {$0$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (3+0.1,-0.2) {$1$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (3+0.1,2-0.2) {$0$};
\node[anchor=south west] at (3,1-0.25) {$?$};
\draw[->] (0,0) --node [below,midway,font=\small] {$1-\epsilon$} (3,0) ;
\draw[->] (0,2) --node [above,midway,font=\small] {$1-\epsilon$} (3,2) ;
\draw[->] (0,0) --node [above,midway,font=\small] {$\epsilon$} (3,1) ;
\draw[->] (0,2) --node [below,midway,font=\small] {$\epsilon$} (3,1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```